# How to programatically navigate from an action creator using react-router v4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I decided to update my verison of React Router to version 4 but I hit a wall with this bit of code

```
export const loginUser = ({ emailOrUsername, password }) => {
return (dispatch) => {
    axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/login`, { emailOrUsername, password })
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
        localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);
        browserHistory.push('/feed'); // How do I do this in v4?
      })
      .catch(() => {
        dispatchAuthError('Incorrect log in details.');
      });
  };
};
```

It seems v4 has removed `browserHistory` altogether and I can no longer achieve the desired transition as simply. Am I missing something?

Comment: Quite surprised this isn't a more common question, as action creators should be the primary place for writing redirect logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now you can take the router object from the context and pass to the store. You can read more [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4242)

Also you can try use `history` module directly:

```
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'
const history = createHashHistory()
history.push('/feed')
```

Have a look in [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4179)

Comment: Thanks, I just used history directly

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in this: [Redirect](https://react-router.now.sh/Redirect)

You can use this tag to redirect them to another route

Comment: I did initially look into Redirect but it involves rendering a component within my action creator which I want to avoid